# How to invoke Celery task by name

Tags: python, celery

We have a Python application that uses Celery, with RabbitMQ as the Broker. Think of this application as a management application and only puts messages/tasks into the Broker and won't be acting upon them.

There will be another application (which may or may not be Python based) which will be acting upon the messages.

Is it possible for the management application to put a message/task on a Queue when that task doesn't exist in it's codebase? If so, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send new messages to the queue using an AMQP client, a list of existing ones can be found in the rabbitMQ [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html).

How to do it really depends on which client and language you will be using but in principle everything comes to sending a message that complies to the protocol that celery is using:

```
# sample message shown in the celery docs
{"id": "4cc7438e-afd4-4f8f-a2f3-f46567e7ca77",
 "task": "celery.task.PingTask",
 "args": [],
 "kwargs": {},
 "retries": 0,
 "eta": "2009-11-17T12:30:56.527191"}
```

You can find a more detailed description of the messages in the celery docs [here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html).

For instance, if using the kombu client (which is the python one also used by celery) you will do something like this:

```
with Connection("my_broker_url") as connection:
    queue = connection.SimpleQueue(queue_name)
    message = {"id": "4cc7438e-afd4-4f8f-a2f3-f46567e7ca77",
               "task": "celery.task.PingTask",
               "args": [],
               "kwargs": {},
               "retries": 0,
               "eta": "2009-11-17T12:30:56.527191"}
    queue.put(message,
              serializer="json")
```

This is a highly stripped down example from the [kombu docs](http://kombu.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/simple.html)

### Follow up after a bit more of searching around

So I totally forgot to mention [flower](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flower), which is an awesome monitor and management tool for celery. It runs as a daemon and expose both a web interface and a nice Rest API!

I found out that you can send tasks from the flower API and it's as easy as this:

```
POST /api/task/send-task/tasks.add HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:5555

{
    "args": [1, 2]
}
```

There are a few API endpoints that let you do this, with some differences:

- [send-task](http://flower.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#post--api-task-send-task-(.+))
- [async-apply](http://flower.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#post--api-task-send-task-(.+))

But in this case you probably want to user `send-task` as it explicitly states that you don't need the task sources with that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That looks great, thanks for the help! I was hoping for something a little more Celery-esque, almost like a send_raw mechanism?

Comment: I found another solution using the flower management tool (which I didn't know you could use for this as I always used it only for monitoring), probably it's closer to what you need.

Comment: Also forgot about Flower despite using it for years. Is a good shout!

Answer (score 16):

There is a more "Celery-esque" way called [Signatures](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#signatures). Setup a Celery app pointing to the same broker and create a signature for your task:

```
from celery import Celery

celeryapp = Celery(...)

my_task = celeryapp.signature('task.add')
result = my_task.delay(2, 2)
print result.get()
```

Comment: Could you explain what tould "task" be in "'task.add" ?

Comment: @Nachokhan a path. `tasks.py` has `add` function that is a task.

Answer (score 10):

1. Create a new instance of `Celery` or Import from a module.
2. Call `send_task()` method.

   ```
   from twittershell.core import app # Celery Instance from a module
   async_result = app.send_task(name='tasks.followers', args=(529675892, ))
   ```

The signature of `send_task` method is:

```
    def send_task(self, name, args=None, kwargs=None, countdown=None,
              eta=None, task_id=None, producer=None, connection=None,
              router=None, result_cls=None, expires=None,
              publisher=None, link=None, link_error=None,
              add_to_parent=True, reply_to=None, **options):
```